# Group By in Soql

Tags: apex, soql, query, compile-error, group-by

I need to group data on the basis of two fields "description" and "createdDate" in soql.

```
Select Subject, WhatId, what.name, Owner.name, Owner.Id, IsVisibleInSelfService, ActivityDate, LastModifiedDate From Task Where whoId =: contactId Group By(Description, createdDate).
```

But it is throwing an error:

> Unknown error parsing query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few different issues with your code.

- All fields in your `SELECT` clause must be in your `GROUP BY` clause or wrapped in an aggregate operation.
- You can't `GROUP BY` a `Datetime` field (chances two records share the same value are extremely low). If you want to count just the date portion, use `DAY_ONLY`.
- You have a trailing `.` character in your query. If that is not a typo and you did include it, it will cause your query to fail.

The following query should work, for example:

```
SELECT
    Description, DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate), count(Id),
    MIN(LastModifiedDate), MAX(LastModifiedDate),
    MIN(ActivityDate), MAX(ActivityDate),
    COUNT_DISTINCT(WhatId)
FROM Task
WHERE WhoId = :contactId
GROUP BY Description, DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate)
```

If you really need values from the other fields, you should question why you are grouping in the first place. If you want to include them in your `SELECT` clause, you need to either `GROUP BY` them as well or decide on the proper aggregation method to apply to them.